# Помогите разобраться с mask в html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Кусочек кода:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(level1, 0, 0);
ctx.save();
ctx.fillRect(0,0,mask.width,mask.height);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-in";
ctx.drawImage(hero,0,0);
ctx.restore();
```

Пытаюсь сделать маску для героя. Но получается вот такой глюк.

[image: hero]

---

Структура такая:

1) Слой backgorund прописанный в css (его мы видим).

2) Backgorund уровня в html5 canvas там леса, трава под ногами (не отображается).

3) Маска для Hero.

4) Сам Hero.

---

Ожидание: background c травой и с вырезанным героем.

Реальность: маска работает, но срезает backgorund of canvas.

Похоже, что ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-in"; распространяется на весь context, а не на добавленные слои. Подскажите, пожалуйста как можно исправить? Может быть надо в отдельном контексте это всё рисовать?

Comment: у вас герой в исходном изображении на прозрачном фоне? если да, то зачем вам вообще менять "режимы смешивания"(не знаю как правильно это назвать) Рисуете background, в стандартном режиме "source-over" герой после нарисуется поверх. это же и надо? или проблема в другом?

Comment: @noadev, нет не прозрачный. дело в том, что маска позволяет больше возможностей делать. например, с помощью нее облака можно делать. а обычным png так не сделаешь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, всё очень просто. Надо было просто разобраться с игрой состояний globalCompositeOperation.

```js
$(function() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var truck, logo, backgroundlevel;
  var newColor = "red";

  var imageURLs = [];
  var imagesOK = 0;
  var imgs = [];
  imageURLs.push("mask.png");
  imageURLs.push("image.jpg");
  imageURLs.push("backgorund.jpg");
  loadAllImages();

  function loadAllImages() {
    for (var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {
      var img = new Image();
      imgs.push(img);
      img.onload = function() {
        imagesOK++;
        imagesAllLoaded();
      };
      img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }
  }

  var imagesAllLoaded = function() {
    if (imagesOK == imageURLs.length) {

      truck = imgs[0];
      logo = imgs[1];
      backgroundlevel = imgs[2];
      start();
    }
  };


  function start() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(logo, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
    ctx.drawImage(truck, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
    ctx.drawImage(backgroundlevel, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";


  }


});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ivory;
  padding: 20px;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=253></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```